# Is circle a "completed" road in Kids of Carcassonne?

Tags: my-first-carcassonne

In Kids of Carcassonne game basic rule is to complete road. In rules it is written (translating from my localized version - Slovak/Czech):

> Road is completed in moment when both ends end in house or elsewhere in country. Road is closed also with crossroads, or city (place surrounded with walls).

Circular road does not fit this definition. So should it be considered "completed" or not?

[image: Kids of Carcassonne circular road]

If cicle does not count as "completed" road it could be used against opponents, that is why I am primarily asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A road is also closed when it forms a complete loop.
>   If a part of a closed road has a color that no
>   player is using, nothing is played on that part.

http://riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_313_gameRules.pdf

This is from the rules for Die Kinder von Carcassone. As this is German for "The Kids of Carcassone", I assume it is the same game.

Comment: Thank you, loop part is not part of my rules (Slovak, Czech localization). Only second sentence is there.